Simple python QT app with NixOs and pyqt6
Trying to figure out how to setup a super basic Dev Shell for working on a QT6+Python app. I cant seem to get anything able to run the most minimal example.
It would expect the basic poetry template would work for a single dependency, but I can not seem to find any good pattern for running a simple PythonQT app with a Nix dev shell. I've been through a bunch of different Nix/python patterns, but none that can launch a basic pyqt app.
Using the basic python (that uses poetry2nix) it seems like this should be straight forward
nix flake new --template templates#python qttest
cd qttest
nix develop
poetry add pyqt6

Running it with `poetry run python sample_package/main.py throws
ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

But more strangely exiting from the nix shell and run nix develop again it fails when that pyqt6 dependency is listed in the poetry config. (I did also throw qt6.full to the packages list in generated flake.nix)
> Running phase: qtPreHook
> Running phase: unpackPhase
> unpacking source archive /nix/store/faslxcvp4ap0ij2m204nhvi52gykgp7p-PyQt6-6.7.0.tar.gz
> source root is PyQt6-6.7.0
> setting SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH to timestamp 1713628695 of file PyQt6-6.7.0/PKG-INFO
> Running phase: patchPhase
> applying patch /nix/store/1jaciw5pjmh8ss3vigr6brcf5br0f48g-confirm-license.patch
> patching file project.py
> Hunk #1 FAILED at 163.
> 1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file project.py.rej

I can however just create a basic flake with
devShells.${system}.default = pkgs.mkShell {
     packages = [ pkgs.python3 pkgs.qt6.full pkgs.python311Packages.pyqt6 ];
};

and it runs a simple hello world qt app fine: just using `python testapp.py". Doing it this way means I am forced to solely use Nix for python dependencies, which isn't ideal.
So how in the world would I setup just the most basic Python + pyqt dev shell

I don't know Nix but libGL.so.1 is not part of PyQt and you may have to add/install as extra dependency
